# Effects of Try/Catch against Throwing Exceptions in a constructing class' constructor

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, throwable

I was playing around with some of my code and came across something I didn't fully understand. I have a class called SentimentClassifier, the constructor of which looks like this:

```
public SentimentClassifier(final int nGramToBeUsed)  {
    try {
        classifier = (DynamicLMClassifier<?>) AbstractExternalizable.readObject(new File(etc));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have another class which creates this one, like so:

```
public TwitterManager(final int nGramToBeUsed) {
    sentimentClassifier = new SentimentClassifier(nGramToBeUsed);
}
```

If I run the code like this, everything works fine. But if I change the first class from using `try/catch` to `throw` the exception, like so:

```
public SentimentClassifier(final int nGramToBeUsed) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException  {
    classifier = (DynamicLMClassifier<?>) AbstractExternalizable.readObject(new File(etc));
}
```

Suddenly the second class complains that the `IOException` isn't being handled. Why is this thrown only for the `thrown` exception and not for the `try/catch`?

Comment: Many of Java's IO methods (such as the constructor for `File` require that the methods be in a try/catch block.

Comment: @Xynariz: Would you have a link to the appropriate documentation? I did look up the API but didn't see anything. Could have just missed it.

Comment: [link here](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/docs/api/com/aliasi/util/AbstractExternalizable.html#readObject(java.io.File)) - that IOException, like most exceptions, must be "caught, or declared to be thrown".

Comment: @Xynariz: I get it now. Didn't realise that when it is thrown it is the responsibility of the calling party to deal with it. Thanks

Comment: Read the other answers - they say the same thing, but explain it better than I did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call a method `M1` from another method `M2`:

- If some code in `M1` raises some *Checked Exception*, and the method `M1` itself handles it, rather than throwing it, you don't have to worry about the exception while calling it.
- Now, if the exception raised in `M1`, is not being handled in `M1` itself, rather it is propagated up the stack trace, then `M1` must declare that exception in the throws clause. This is just for the convenience of the calling method to know that it should be ready to handle those exception in case they are thrown. This is only the case with *Checked Exception*.
- But if the calling method `M2`, doesn't handle that exception, it has the option to re-declare that exception to be thrown in it's own throws clause, in which case the exception will be propagated further up the stack trace.
- If method `M2` does neither of the previous two task, you will get a compiler error. Because you haven't given any proper path or way to handle the exception that can be thrown.

Note all the above arguments are true for *Checked Exception* only. For Unchecked exception, you don't need to handle it yourself, neither you need to declare it in throws clause.

---

**Suggested Read:**

- [Java: checked vs unchecked exception explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6115896/1679863)
- [Unchecked Exception controversies](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html)
- [JLS - The Kinds and Causes of Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.1)

Answer (score 4):

In Java, if a method declares that throws an `Exception` (other than `RuntimeException`), callers must handle the exception. They can do this one of two ways: catch it, or declare that they themselves throw it.

You moved the handling of these two exceptions from the `SentimentClassifier` constructor to its callers.

Answer (score 3):

If the constructor declares any exceptions, the calling code must handle them or declare them. After all, the constructor could throw/propagate these exceptions, and any code that calls it must handle them.

Answer (score 2):

When you **catch** an exception, it means that you will deal with it on the catch block, and its consequences, so  the external code can continue to progress without being warned about the internal exception.

If your exception is **thrown**, you are forcing by contract to any creator/invoker class to deal with any declared exception that could be produced during the initialization/execution process, as it can be critical for the business logic.

In this case, if the exceptions that can be generated during init are critical, and could stop the class from working properly, they should be thrown, as the creator class `TwitterManager` could have a disfuncional or partially initialized instance of the `SentinelClassifier` object, leading to unexpected errors.